# GAE (Python) Urlfetch 60 Second Timeout Issue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, timeout, urlfetch

I ran into this 60s timeout issue when my `GAE` server communicates to an `EC2 REST` server. On the `GAE` side, my task is to uploading a `csv` file, parsing its information and sending each row as a request to the `REST` server. I am using multiple threading and task queue to reduce the request time but still got timed-out when the file is large. Below is an example of my code and I appreciate any suggestions.

```
from threading import Thread
import Queue

thread_count = 10 #the number of theading
job_q = Queue.Queue() #a job queue

def html_table(row_inp_all):
    while True:
        row_inp_temp_all = row_inp_all.get()
        all_dic = {"row_inp_temp_all": row_inp_temp_all}
        data = json.dumps(all_dic)
        url=url_part1 + '/przm/' + jid 
        response = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload=data, method=urlfetch.POST, headers=http_headers, deadline=60)   
        output_val = json.loads(response.content)['result']


def loop_html(thefile):
    reader = csv.reader(thefile.file.read().splitlines())
    header = reader.next()
    for row in reader:
        job_q.put(row)
    all_threads = [Thread(target=html_table, args=(job_q, )) for j in range(thread_count)]
    for x in all_threads:
        x.start()
    for x in all_threads:
        job_q.put(None)
    for x in all_threads:
        x.join()
```

Comment: Can you do it in the background?  If so, a google app-engine task queue might be the ticket:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/

Comment: It is very rare that you should need to resort to using threads on appengine and if the code is not waiting on resources it will probably run slower.  async methods and task queues are all you should probably need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard limit for any request of 60 seconds and if you want more time than that you should use [Task Queues API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) which can run in the background for up to 10 minutes which should be more than enough in your case.

Before diving deep into the Task Queues you could try the [background work with the deferred library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) which is actually using Task Queue API but makes it much easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks and will this task queues work well with threading? or I need to redo the whole structure....